# Surjectivity and little Picard's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, entire-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be an entire function which is not a constant function.

Let $p(z) = az^3 + bz^2 + cz + d$ be a polynomial such that $p'(z) = k(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)$ for some $\alpha, \beta, k \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\alpha \neq \beta.$

Then $g(z) = p(f(z)) $ is surjective.

$\textbf{Attempt}$ Clearly, $p$ is not a constant polynomial by the condition on $p'$. Therefore, $g$ is a nonconstant entire function.

By Little Picard's Theorem, $g$ is surjective or there exists $z_0$ such that $g(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_0\}.$

Since $f$ is a nonconstant entire fucntion, by the Little Picard's theorem, either $f(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}$, or there exists $z_1$ such that $f(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_1\}.$

If $f$ is surjective, then $g = p\circ f$ is surjective because $p$ is also surjective. So assume that $f(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}\setminus \{z_1\}.$

Set $h(z) = f(z) - z_1.$ Then $h$ is an entire function which is non-vanishing on $\mathbb{C}$. So there exists a nonconstant holomorphic function $H(z)$ such that $$f(z)-z_1=h(z) = e^{H(z)}.$$

To show $g$ is surjective, fix $y \in \mathbb{C}.$ Then I want to find $\gamma$ such that $$a(e^{H(\gamma)}+z_1)^3+b(e^{H(\gamma)}+z_1)^2+c(e^{H(\gamma)}+z_1)+d=af^3(\gamma) + bf^2(\gamma) + cf(\gamma) + d = y.$$

Not sure how to proceed from this point. Please gives some help !!

Comment: Hint: the condition on the polynomial means the preimage of any point under $p$ has either three (generic) or two (critical values) points. In particular if $g$ is not surjective and misses $w$ you get that $f$ misses at least two points since its image is disjoint of the preimage of $w$ under the polynomial $p$

Comment: I am not sure about the first part you mentioned about the condition on polynomial $p$. So basically, $p'$ is a polynomial with degree 2 with distinct roots. From here I can conclude that either $b$ is not zero or $c$ is not zero, but not both of them. I am not sure how you go from here to conclude that $|p^{-1}(\{x\})| = 2 $  or $3$. As far as I know, derivative $p'$ does not give much information about range of $p$. Is what you mentioned a kind of Theorem in complex analysis ?

Comment: $p$ is degree $3$ so $p(z)-a$ is degree three so generally will have $3$ distinct roots; it will have $2$ precisely at the critical values (the values $p(\alpha), p(\beta)$) - the only case there is a triple root is if the roots of the derivative are equal ($p-a$ cube and then you easily check that). For any constant $a$, $p(z)-a$ has same derivative as $p(z)$ and double roots are roots of the polynomial and the derivative, while triple roots are double roots of the derivative etc

Comment: Thank you !! I got it now. Actually, the fact that $|p^{-1}(\{z\})| > 1$ for any $z$ should be enough.

Comment: $|p^{-1}(\{z\})| > 1$ is insured precisely by the condition on the derivative (in general for any degree $n \ge 3$ you need the derivative to have a zero of order $n-1 \ge 2$  - or equivalently the derivative to be a perfect power of its degree - for the pathology $|p^{-1}(\{z\})| = 1$ to happen);